# Amazon S3 Transfer Manager directory upload - Hashes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

Currently, We implement S3 individual file uploads by adding MD5 hashes to the upload request to validate our file transfer. But now we want to leverage AWS S3 Transfer Manager for directory upload. So, now how to check for Hashes of the folders/files uploaded?

I have scouted through the documentation available on Transfer Manager but couldn't find any information on Hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the SDK has already taken care of that for you. The AWS Signature Version 4 calculation includes the SHA256 of the payload. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html)]